# Correlation between webkit Safari and webkitGTK

Tags: browser, safari, webkit, webkitgtk

Which version of (Mac) Safari Webkit is WebKitGTK 2.30 based on?

Comment: If you have access to their programming API, you can use [`WebKitVersion`](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/webkit2gtk-4.0-WebKitVersion.html) procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [webkit-2.3.1/WebKitLibraries/ChangeLog](http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/releases/WebKitGTK/webkit-2.3.1/WebKitLibraries/ChangeLog), the newest entry is from `2013-10-21`, which correlates to [Safari 7's release date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Safari_7),

That's WebKit 537.71.